# Realizar proceso de compra

Tags: wordpress

Estoy desarrollando una web donde habrán 3 productos en si no más.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando cliquen en comprar el producto vaya directamente a la pagina de rellenar un formulario con los datos solicitados.

Tal como lo hace esta web:

http://www.nienumber.eu/prices/

No se si es necesario utilizar woocommerce o se puede hacer viía php?

Comment: si bien tu solo preguntaste si se puede hacer con php pues la respuesta es claro, ya que controlas tu carrito desde el back.. perooo yo te recomiendo que veas https://www.opencart.com/ a mi me ayudo muchiiiisimo.

Comment: Saludos amigo..

Comment: Vale puede ser que la pregunta no sea la adecuada, lo que quiero decir es como podria realizar un carrito de compra con php sin utilizar woocommerce ya que solo son 3 servicios con diferente precio. el boton de registrarse de cada formulario lo puedo enviar al carrito con el importa a pagar ya al tpv? No creo que me sirva opencart. Gracias